# How to sub route with lazy loaded module?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

With the new router there really is no need to use auxiliary routes, and if you are lazy loading a module that has it's own routes and router then it's highly unlikely you will even get that to work based on existing examples (I tried for an entire day using every example on stackoverflow to no avail). So what does a working example of this look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Angular 2.3.1 (angular-cli) with router 3.3.1, this is the working solution I've come up with.

Top level router, app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: AuthComponent },
  { path: 'analyze', loadChildren: 'app/analyze/analyze.module#AnalyzeModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Lazy loaded module (AnalyzeModule) router, whose respective component was output into the original router-outlet in app-component:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '', component: AnalyzeComponent,
      children: [
         { path: 'charts', component: ChartsComponent },
         { path: 'graphs', component: GraphsComponent },
      ]
   }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AnalyzeRoutingModule { }
```

Lazy loaded component html:

```
 <li><a href="#" [routerLink]="['charts']" routerLinkActive="active">Charts</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" [routerLink]="['graphs']" routerLinkActive="active">Graphs</a></li>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Note that since you are lazy loading a module that the new default path is blank just as it would be in the router above it. The key here is listing the routes as children routes and NOT using an auxiliary router-outlet (it will fail no matter what you do with this particular setup). Doing so means that you can just use a normal router-outlet with normal routerLinks (no auxiliary outlets with all the mess that comes with it), without overwriting the lazy component loaded in the original router-outlet in the app-component.html (or whatever the next level up was) which is what happens if you do not use an auxiliary outlet and do not list the subroutes as children at the same time.

This isn't really a new solution, but more of a mixture of various solutions for this particular setup. Hopefully this will save someone some time and frustration.